# Listen for a scroll event in <object>

Tags: javascript, html

I have a PDF in an **HTML** object tag like so:

```
<object type="application/pdf" data="https://termsfeed.com/assets/pdf/privacy-policy-template.pdf"></object>
```

and I would like to run some code when the PDF is scrolled. However, attaching a scroll event listener to the object element doesn't work. What is the correct way to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, one of the issues with `Object` is it is often the least reliable/supported means to show a PDF, here is that CORS reference as embed, iframe and object so Object needs a href as a fail back message to explain which remote file was intended for download.
`<a href="` https://www.termsfeed.com/public/uploads/2021/12/sample-privacy-policy-template.pdf `"></a>`
will work as its a remote link so I can see that PDF as a replacement tab.

However imbedded in-line

[image]

**So back to the question about scrolling**, clearly scrolling in that page can only apply to the scrollbar for the HTML, it cannot have any effect on those imbeded objects, even if they had scrollbars. Those areas are secured client user hardware access areas, not HTML access objects.

Answer (score -2):

```js
document.getElementById('pdfContainer').addEventListener('scroll', function () {
  console.log('scrolling');
});
```

```css
object {
  height: 1200px;
}

#pdfContainer {
  height: 500px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id='pdfContainer'>
   <object type="application/pdf" data="https://termsfeed.com/assets/pdf/privacy-policy-template.pdf"></object>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm testing this out and this does not appear to work in an environment where the PDF actually loads and the scrolling takes place inside the PDF.

Answer (score -2):

I have done this is my project to detect the scroll end. Please paste the following code:

1. ***.html file***

```
<object #myIframe id="framei" data="../assets/eula.html" (load)="onIframeLoad()" style="height: 500px; width: 540px;"></object>

                                   or

<iframe #myIframe src="../assets/eula.html" style="height: 500px; width: 540px;" (load)="onIframeLoad()"></iframe>
```

2. ***.ts file***

```
     @ViewChild('myIframe') myIframe: ElementRef;

      onIframeLoad() {
        const iframe = this.myIframe.nativeElement;
        iframe.contentWindow.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
          console.log("Scrolling")
          if (this.isIframeAtBottom(iframe)) {
            console.log('Iframe scrolled to the bottom');
            // Perform your desired action here
          } 
        });
      }
    
      isIframeAtBottom(iframe: any): boolean {
        const iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
        return (Math.floor(Math.abs(iframeDoc.body.scrollHeight - iframeDoc.body.scrollTop - iframeDoc.body.clientHeight)))===0; 
      }
```

Comment: "html file" — The question is asking about a PDF, not an HTML document.

Comment: @Quentin Please check again, the question is about a PDF embedded in a HTML object, right?

Comment: "the question is about a PDF embedded in a HTML object, right? " — Yes, however you said: `data="../assets/eula.html"` — That URL points to an HTML document not to a PDF. So you're embedding an HTML document in an object, not a PDF.